# Вопрос по рекурсии Python

Tags: python, рекурсия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при выполнении кода на степень:

```
def power(a, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return a * power(a, n - 1)

print(power(4, 8))
```

Рекурсия работает правильно, а при коде ускоренного возведения в степень (aⁿ = (a²)ⁿ/² при четном n):

```
def power(a, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return power(a, (n // 2)) * power(a, (n // 2))
    else:
        return a * power(a, n - 1)

print(power(4, 8))
```

Не прекращается после строки `if n == 0:`. а продолжает прыгать между if elif else, и делить / отнимать n. И вместо "ускоренного возведения" происходит раза в 2 больше рекурсий, чем при простом перемножении.

Comment: Вы вызываете один и тот же `power(a, (n // 2))` два раза — вот он и вычисляется тоже два раза и таким образом создаёт иллюзию прыгания (на самом деле ничего не прыгает)

Comment: Если вы замените это на что-то вроде `x = power(a, (n // 2)); return x * x` то иллюзия прыгания исчезнет

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что вы 2 раза вызываете функцию (`power(a, (n // 2)) * power(a, (n // 2))`). Из-за этого они выполняются независимо и весь смысл ускорения теряется. Обычно эта функция выглядит так:

```
def power(a, n):
    if n == 0: 
        return 1
    if n % 2 == 0: # <--- заменил elif на if
        return power(a*a, (n // 2)) # <---
    # <--- убрал elif
    return a * power(a, n - 1)
```

Или так:

```
def power(a, n):
    if n == 0: 
        return 1
    if n % 2 == 0: # <--- заменил elif на if
        return power(a*a, (n // 2)) # <---
    # <--- убрал elif
    return a * power(a*a, (n-1)//2) # <--- изменил вызов
```

**UPD**
Однако, спасибо [Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1432963/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-python/1432972?noredirect=1#comment2555654_1432972), стоит использовать не `a*a`, а `power(..)**2`:

```
def power(a, n):
    if n == 0: 
        return 1
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return power(a, (n // 2))**2
    return a * power(a, n - 1)
```

```
def power(a, n):
    if n == 0: 
        return 1
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return power(a, (n // 2))**2
    return a * power(a, (n-1)//2)**2
```

Comment: Неочевидный факт: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1415409/416121

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо за информацию. внесу поправку в ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Анализ производительности. Для простоты примем что `n` - степень двойки. В этом случае функцию можно упростить до такой:

```
def power(a, n):
    if n == 1:
        return a
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return power(a, n // 2) * power(a, n // 2)
```

По времени работы она не отличается от вашей, зато анализировать её проще. Пусть `T(k)` - время работы для `n = 2^k`. Тогда:

> ```
> T(0) = 1
> T(k + 1) = 2T(k) + <время умножения> + <мелочи>
> ```

Если время умножения и мелочи отбросить, получится:

> ```
> T(0) = 1
> T(k + 1) >= 2^T(k)
> ```

По индукции получаем:

> ```
> T(k) >= 2^k = n
> ```

То есть, сложность новой функции линейная (или хуже) по `n` в случае когда `n` степень двойки. Для не-степеней двойки доказывается тот же результат.

Переделаем код:

```
def power(a, n):
    if n == 1:
        return a
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return power(a, n // 2) ** 2
```

Уравнение для этого случая лишилось множителя двойки:

> ```
> T(k + 1) = T(k) + <время умножения> + <мелочи>
> ```

Если, для простоты, опустить времена умножений, то получим уравнение `T(k) >= k = log n`. Сложность стала близка к логарифмической!

Хотя анализ дыряв как решето, ясно видно что во втором случае число умножений логарифмическое, в первом - линейное. Логично ожидать соответствующей разницы в производительности.

**P.S.** Быстрый код в вашем стиле выглядел бы так:

```
def power(a, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return power(a, (n // 2)) ** 2
    else:
        return a * power(a, n - 1)
```